# Why isnt the print statement printing

Tags: python

```
mood = input("Enter mood :sad,happy,excited") for x in mood:
    if x == "sad":
        print("Listen to x")
        if x == "happy":
            print("listen to a")
            if x == "excited":
                print("listen to b")
```

Answer (score 2):

considering you are a newbie to SO, consider reading the rules and research more before putting up a question.

As for the solution, is you use `for x in mood` it will iterate over the string `mood` and x will become the first letter in `mood`

```py
mood = input("Enter mood :sad,happy,excited")

if mood == "sad":
    print("Listen to x")
elif mood == "happy":
    print("listen to a")
elif mood == "excited":
    print("listen to b")
else:
    print("invalid input")
```

Comment: Also, the way that's indented, it will only check for "happy" if it already matches "sad", which of course will never happen.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary

```
dictionary = {"sad":"Listen to x", "happy":"listen to a", "excited":"listen to b"}
query = input("Enter mood :sad,happy,excited")
print(dictionary.get(query, "invalid input"
```

Comment: or `print(dictionary.get(query, "invalid input"))`

Comment: Oh cool, didn't know .get had that feature